# display values of enum type from using integer

Tags: c++

i want to get the current state by using enumType variable. but with these code i cant get the value.. for example if enumType = 3 state should be crawl...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int enumType;

    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    enumType = rand()%3;

    enum state{
        stand,
        walk,
        run,
        crawl,
    };

    state currentState;
    (int)currentState =enumType;

    cout<<state.currentState;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dude. C/C++ doesn't work that way :).  If you want "meaningful names" (like "enum state 3" == "crawl"), then you get to map the enum value to the text string yourself.

You can create a static table, you can use a "switch/case" block, you can use an STL map.  There are lots of options - but you've got to do it yourself, manually.  It's not automagically built in to the language (like C#).

Answer (score 2):

```
string strState;

switch(currentState)
{
   case stand:
     strState = "Stand";
   break;

   case walk:
     strState = "walk";
   break;

   case run:
     strState = "run";
   break;

   case crawl:
     strState = "crawl";
   break;
}

cout << strState;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


int main()
{

srand(time(0));


enum state{
    stand,
    walk,
    run,
    crawl,
};
state min=stand;
state max=crawl;
state enumType = (state)(rand()%((max-min)+1));

state currentState;
currentState =enumType;

printf("  %i  ",currentState);


return 0;
}
```

and the outcome is:

1
1
0
1
0
2
...
each time running, different values between 0-2 because it is "flooring"
new edit: (max-min)+1) in the modulo thing

Comment: Thanks ,,,, i have a C++ assignment i think you can help me on that,,, if you can please send me your email address.. to sureshbandara@yahoo.com then i will mail you.. please help me on this

Comment: crawl-stand=3. %3 will give only you 0, 1 or 2 or stand, walk, and run. But no 3=crawl. Please fix your off-by-one bug.